# Add guest invitation via Microsoft Graph and App Credentials give Method Not Found

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to develop an app similar to what was asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58659826/adding-guest-users-to-azure-ad-with-an-automated-script)

I have configured the app in the Azure Portal with the proper permissions and followed the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

The application appears to be getting the proper token from AD using the scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

After the call is made, it responds with a "Method Not Found" error.

```
Code: UnknownError
Message: Method not allowed
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2020-10-11T21:36:03
    request-id: ...
    client-request-id: ...
ClientRequestId: ...
```

The request-id, client-request-id, and ClientRequestId all have the same value.

Is there a way to troubleshoot why this error occurs with the Ids returned?
Is there something I am missing in my configuration?

The purpose of this app is to self-register volunteers for a Give Camp we are holding and will use Microsoft Teams as the collaboration tool.  If there is a better way to do this, I am open to suggestions.

The code can be found here https://github.com/swogc/GiveCamp-Teams

Permissions granted for app:
[image: Permissions granted for app]

Comment: Make sure in your app registration, you've configured the API permissions and clicked the button to grant admin consent.

Comment: Could you share your HTTP request url? Creating invitation needs to use **POST**. And permissions can also need to grant admin consent as Jason said.

Comment: @PamelaPeng - This is using the Microsoft Graph library, so I would assume it was doing a post. [Ref Line](https://github.com/swogc/GiveCamp-Teams/blob/3629f8f5363c7227485e0b874d3bc2fbd32ec734/SWOGCInvite/Services/InvitationService.cs#L47)

Comment: @JasonP I believe I have the correct permissions configured.  I updated the post with a screenshot of the permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems both permissions and post are all right. If the application is authorized without user, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS) and use [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider) to call the MS graph API.

```
string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                            .Create(clientId)
                            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                            .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var invitation = new Invitation
{
    InvitedUserEmailAddress = "pamela@xxx",
    InviteRedirectUrl = "https://southwestohiogivecamp.org",
    
};

await graphClient.Invitations.Request().AddAsync(invitation);
```